# Facebook app ID is responding only name and facebook id while facebook integration in android

Tags: android, facebook

Facebook app ID is responding only name and facebook id while facebook integration in android in Response only name and id come. Other profile info is not coming. Even default data not provide.

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
       try {
       //    response = facebook.request("me/friends");
             response = facebook.request("me");

             if (response == null || response.equals("") || response.equals("false") || response.contains("error")) {
                   Log.v("Error", response.toString());
             } else {
                   JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
             }
       } catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println(e);
   }
```

Comment: you did not request any other data, so why should it show up?

Comment: I am new. so pls tell me how to request in this code for other basic profile info like email profile image etc.   Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```html
loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);

List < String > permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("user_photos", "email",
 "user_birthday", "public_profile", "AccessToken");
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager,
new FacebookCallback < LoginResult > () {@Override
 public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

  System.out.println("onSuccess");

  String accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken()
   .getToken();
  Log.i("accessToken", accessToken);

  GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
  loginResult.getAccessToken(),
  new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {@Override
   public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,
   GraphResponse response) {
    Log.i("LoginActivity", response.toString());
    try {
     id = object.getString("id");
     try {
      URL profile_pic = new URL(
       "http://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture?type=large");
      Log.i("profile_pic",
      profile_pic + "");

     } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
     name = object.getString("name");
     email = object.getString("email");
     gender = object.getString("gender");
     birthday = object.getString("birthday");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
  });
  Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
  parameters.putString("fields",
   "id,name,email,gender, birthday");
  request.setParameters(parameters);
  request.executeAsync();
 }

 @Override
 public void onCancel() {
  System.out.println("onCancel");
 }

 @Override
 public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
  System.out.println("onError");
  Log.v("LoginActivity", exception.getCause().toString());
 }
});
```

Comment: Using your code In most of the cases email id is not in response. Only one User got his email id.